# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't link the library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, c++17

I'm trying to build a simple C++ program in Visual Studio 2017. I had no issues while doing it on Linux but for some reason it doesn't work on Windows.

Here is the program:

```
// CMakeProject1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "CMakeProject1.h"
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/xchar.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/win_eventlog_sink.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/msvc_sink.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/wincolor_sink.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector<spdlog::sink_ptr> sinks;
    
    sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::win_eventlog_sink_mt>("me"));

    sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::msvc_sink_mt>());
    sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::wincolor_stdout_sink_mt>());
    auto logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("main-logger", begin(sinks), end(sinks));

    SPDLOG_LOGGER_CALL(logger, spdlog::level::info, L"{}", L"Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

get_filename_component(Project ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "-" Project ${Project})
project(${Project} CXX C)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    fmt
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
    GIT_TAG        8.0.1 
    )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)
if (NOT fmt_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(fmt)
    add_subdirectory(${fmt_SOURCE_DIR} ${fmt_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
message(STATUS "fmt_SOURCE_DIR = ${fmt_SOURCE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "fmt_BINARY_DIR = ${fmt_BINARY_DIR}")

FetchContent_Declare(
    spdlog
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
    GIT_TAG        v1.9.2
    )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)
if (NOT spdlog_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(spdlog)
    set(SPDLOG_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
    set(SPDLOG_BUILD_BENCH    OFF)
    set(SPDLOG_BUILD_TESTS    OFF)
    add_subdirectory(${spdlog_SOURCE_DIR} ${spdlog_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
message(STATUS "spdlog_SOURCE_DIR = ${spdlog_SOURCE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "spdlog_BINARY_DIR = ${spdlog_BINARY_DIR}")

set(SourceDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(ExecutableSources ${SourceDir}/main.cpp)
set(LinkLibraries fmt::fmt spdlog::spdlog)

set(Executable ${Project})

message(STATUS CMAKE_VERSION = ${CMAKE_VERSION})
message(STATUS LinkLibraries = ${LinkLibraries})

add_executable(${Executable} ${ExecutableSources})
add_definitions(-DSPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT)
target_compile_options(${Executable} PUBLIC ${CompilationFlags})
target_link_libraries(${Executable} PUBLIC ${LinkLibraries})
```

The way I generate a build files is the same way I do it on Linux

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

I then open the solution in Visual Studio 2017 and build it. However I'm getting the following errors:

```
4>main.cpp
4>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl spdlog::details::os::wstr_to_utf8buf(class fmt::v8::basic_string_view<wchar_t>,class fmt::v8::basic_memory_buffer<char,250,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?wstr_to_utf8buf@os@details@spdlog@@YAXV?$basic_string_view@_W@v8@fmt@@AAV?$basic_memory_buffer@D$0PK@V?$allocator@D@std@@@56@@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall spdlog::logger::log_<wchar_t const (&)[13]>(struct spdlog::source_loc,enum spdlog::level::level_enum,class fmt::v8::basic_string_view<wchar_t>,wchar_t const (&)[13])" (??$log_@AAY0N@$$CB_W@logger@spdlog@@IAEXUsource_loc@1@W4level_enum@level@1@V?$basic_string_view@_W@v8@fmt@@AAY0N@$$CB_W@Z)
4>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl spdlog::details::os::utf8_to_wstrbuf(class fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>,class fmt::v8::basic_memory_buffer<wchar_t,250,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &)" (?utf8_to_wstrbuf@os@details@spdlog@@YAXV?$basic_string_view@D@v8@fmt@@AAV?$basic_memory_buffer@_W$0PK@V?$allocator@_W@std@@@56@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall spdlog::sinks::win_eventlog::win_eventlog_sink<class std::mutex>::sink_it_(struct spdlog::details::log_msg const &)" (?sink_it_@?$win_eventlog_sink@Vmutex@std@@@win_eventlog@sinks@spdlog@@MAEXABUlog_msg@details@4@@Z)
4>C:\Users\user\source\repos\CMakeProject1\build\Debug\CMakeProject1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
4>Done building project "CMakeProject1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It looks like Visual Studio 2017 is not linking against the libraries. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Not familiar with the lib but my assumption given this error message would be that the `spdlog` lib is not compiled with the correct options on windows preventing the compilation of optional functionality which you may activate using  by defining the preprocessor symbol `SPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @fabian's comment, you should

```
set(SPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT ON)
```

before the `add_subdirectory` call to [have CMake set that preprocessor symbol for you](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/d368ed586cec5c3c448ba45c114594250fd0fa72/CMakeLists.txt#L221-L237).